How many extra unions are required to make a plumbed system easily servicable?
In an answer to the question Is it possible to stop weeping between threaded copper joint on sprinkler system?,
@Ecnerwal suggests that the installer

didn't put in enough unions to make it easily serviceable.

How do you work out how many unions are required?
Is there a rule of thumb that works for installations of this type?

Often just thinking about how one would remove Valve #3 once it is all together helps. It is easy to put things together in sequence, harder to pull one out of the line later on. Experience helps.

What here might need to be replaced? (Vacuum breaker is a common one. Electric valves are a common one. Manual valves not that often, but more often than a fitting.) How much do I need to take apart to replace that? (Flanges are another option, more commonly seen in heating systems to permit quick pump swaps than in irrigation systems, but they could be used.) If the system is not threaded pipes as in that question, there are also other ways (unsolder joints, release push-to-connect fittings, and most push-to-connect fittings will rotate so you don't need unions to be able to unscrew threads.)
